# Velocity Scroll Issue with Version 2.0.1

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

An update to the newest version of Velocity (2.0.1) causes an issue related to scroll.  Specifically, the following error message is thrown:

> Error: Velocity: First argument (scroll) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect. Aborting.

The following example works fine with Velocity 1.5: https://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/kBuEi

Since SO requires code, here is the relevant portion from the CodePen:

```
$("#element3").velocity("scroll", { 
  container: $("#container"),
  duration: 800,
  delay: 500
});
```

However, when Velocity 2.0.1 is used instead, it throws the error: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQgOPx

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Just in case people are only reading the question - this is where it's worth reading the Changelog (or in this case the V2_CHANGES.md file) - the API for scrolling has changed to be consistent within Velocity, as a normal animation property :-)

Answer (score 2):

Coder of Velocity V2 here, and going to point at the [V2 Changes](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/master/V2_CHANGES.md) file:

> ## Currently disabled / not updated:
>
> - Scroll (working, but not happy with interface - it's a property if people want to play, alias of scrollTop, there's also scrollLeft)

So it's in, but I'm likely to change the underlying code (the interface will remain identical if/when that happens though), it is however a normal property to animate now (and will stay as such) - so to use it now you'd do something like:

```
$("#container").velocity({scrollTop: "500px"}, {
  duration: 800,
  delay: 500
});
```

If you want to scroll down to another element, then you'd need to find the relative position of that element compared to the first (which should be a separate issue, but I will add to the wiki when it's done).

Note: I'd encourage people to use `"scrollTop"` instead of `"scroll"` to make it obvious that you're not using `"scrollLeft"`.

Note2: `"scrollTop"` is in 2.0.1, the other ones will be in the next beta 2.0.2 - but are in the repo right now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `scroll` action is available in [v1.5.0 (Line: 3161)](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.js)  but appears to be missing from [v2.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.1/velocity.js)

Comment: Actually it's in V2 as a normalisation, the code has changed completely and it's not something you can simply compare the V2 final output file to the V1 source file to see.